# Why mongoose saving raise error when using with GraphQL?

Tags: mongoose, graphql

I added this GraphQL resolver function,

```
switchEventSellingStarted: async(_, {name, sellingStarted}) => {
      const e1 = Event.findOne({name: name})
      if (!e1) {
        throw new Error(`Couldn't find post with id ${name}`);
      }
      e1.sellingStarted = sellingStarted;
      await e1.save();
      return e1;
    }
```

and when executing resolver, got this error, why?

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "e1.save is not a function",
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an await in front of `Event.findOne`. Without it, `e1` is a Promise, and there is no method named `save` on a Promise object.